# Ruby: Incrementing within a Method

Tags: ruby, methods, count, increment

I am trying to create a CLI arithmetic quiz program and am having difficulty keeping the score within the method. I get the following error message whenever I attempt to increment the score variable (which is declared).

```
main.rb:17:in `ask': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from main.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

The code is pasted below. I believe I need to use the 'return' statement to do the increment but I am unsure how this works. (Even if this is not the problem, I'd still welcome any help from anyone to explain how you use boolean return values to count.)

```
def ask(question, answer)
    print question
    user_answer = gets.chomp
    if user_answer == answer
        puts "Correct!"
        score += 1
    else
        puts "Wrong! The answer was #{answer}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your score variable **is not** declared. You didn't show class implementation, but I suggest you to use `attr_writer :score`(or `attr_accessor :score` if you want both get and set var) and set initial value in `initialize` method.

Answer (score 2):

All local variables inside a method are visible only within the method. Class variables have greater visibility, so renaming `score` to `@score` (both inside and outside the method) should be a remedy.